# Prevent Duplicate Entries in SQL Application

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an application that's running on two different machines.
The use of the application is pretty simple, we scan a product and it associates the **product_id** and creates a **Unique_ID** that's auto-incremental.

*Ex*: **U00001** then the next is **U00002**

My problem is while both the machines are running, sometimes the **Unique_ID** is the same for two different products. It's like the creation of the **Unique_ID** happens at the same time so it duplicates the entry.

What's the best approach for this? Is it a connection problem?

Comment: Why are you not using an `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE`? Then the problem can't happen. You don't show *how* you're creating this ID, but you're clearly not using the correct tools for the job.

Comment: How would you suggest to use the `Identity` or `Sequence`?
I'm using  `INSERT INTO table_association VALUES xx`

Comment: Btw @Larnu I'm not using `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE` because I didn't know those existed.  An answer like @Charlieface is way more helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `SEQUENCE` or `IDENTITY` column, and then a computed column concatenates the `U` onto it

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable (
  ID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  product_id varchar(30),
  Unique_ID AS FORMAT(ID, '"U"0000)
)
```

Or

```
CREATE SEQUENCE YourTable_IDs AS int START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MAXVALUE 9999;

CREATE TABLE YourTable (
  ID int PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR YourTable_IDs),
  product_id varchar(30),
  Unique_ID AS FORMAT(ID, '"U"0000)
)
```

Comment: If my column is already created is that solution still doable?

And my  primary key is on another column, is this a problem?

Comment: Bit difficult. You need to create a new column, `SET IDENTITY INSERT ON`, copy the data in, drop the old column and `sp_rename`